# Heat to ARM template conversion via tool present on git hum :: exceptions and error

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

was trying to build the stack on Azure platform but somehow stuck in converting heat template to ARM template...

Have modified openstack.yaml template and tried converting yaml  to ARM using Heat2ARM conversion tool..but while executing the heat2arm.exe getting below exceptions -

```
Exception: Nova image "ubuntu_1404_image" cannot be mapped to an Azure equivalent. Please update the "CONF.nova_vm_image_map" configuration option
```

can anyone suggest what needs to be done here?

Comment: can you at least give out a link to the repo?

Comment: https://github.com/cloudbase/heat2arm